# Bind selected column from datatable into datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

My Sql stored procedure returns a `DataTable` "dt". How would I use Selected columns from that datatable and bind them to specified values in my `DataGrid`?

I am currently using this:

```
 DataView view = new DataView(dt);
 DataTable cat = view.ToTable(true,"categoryID", "category");
```

How would I bind the category ID and category columns in my `DataGrid`?

Here are my `DataGrid` columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="        " />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) approach here.

The DataTable should be managed by the `ViewModel` and the the columns that you want to display use can be made available to your view by properties of the `ViewModel`.

**[EDIT]**

The amount of work you would need to invest is dependent on what you want to achieve. If you only want to display the values it might be sufficient if you convert the `DataTable` into a `ObservableCollection` and then bind `ObservableCollection` to the UI element.

Or, you can bind the `DataTable` directly to your `DataGrid` and set the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` property.

You can find an example here: [Bind Datatable with DataGrid in WPF & MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284026/bind-datatable-with-datagrid-in-wpf-mvvm)

**[EDIT 2]**

In short, a ViewModel is the class that should be visible to your WPF window. It contains some public properties that signal the View when the underlying data has changed by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
The advantage of this approach is that the View gets decoupled from the business logic that works with the actual data. It does not need to be refreshed manually but is automatically informed by the ViewModel. WPF was strongly designed to make use of the MVVM pattern, so if you dig into it, you will find it very rewarding to work with.

It makes working with WPF very easy and helps structuring class responsibilities.

A nice tutorial on how to get into using the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) approach and how to use ViewModels can be found in this MSDN article: [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). That one helped me a great deal to understand MVVM.

Comment: could you please elaborate.how would i use a viewmodel

Comment: Hi @deception1, I added some more information/ links. These will help you to get started into working with ViewModels and MVVM. I strongly suggest that you have a look at the MVVM pattern because it plays its strength especially when using databinding in WPF, which is exactly what you want to do here. You will love it. :-)