# Calculate SUM of "Amount" column in DATAGRID's DataGridTemplateColumn on in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

We have WPF application, In which we use DataGrid on one form.
Now we want to calculate total of "AMOUNT" column of that datagrid on Winddow_Loaded event, So can it will display total of AMOUNT column in one TextBox
when Form get loaded. So how to iterate through all rows in DATAGRID & Calculate Total of "AMOUNT" column.

How to show this total in Footer of WPF Datagrid.?

Comment: How do you populate the `DataGrid`?

Comment: I have populated DataGrid by adding manually rows in it, When we open form in EDIT mode, at that time DATA will be fetched from Database. So Now when we open form in EDIT mode, DATAGRID populated from Database, How to iterate through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284026/bind-datatable-with-datagrid-in-wpf-mvvm) `DataGrid` to `DataTable`. After that you can just iterate through all rows:

```
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (var row in myTable)
        {
            sum += double.Parse(row["AMOUNT"].ToString());
        }
        myTextBox.Text = sum.ToString()
```

Comment: Okay, I will try & Let you Know. Thanks for this

Comment: Will you please help to Convert my DATAGRID into DATATABLE?

Comment: I have converted my DATAGRID Into DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Function to convert DataGrid to DataSet:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    static class ExtClass
    {
     public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
     {
         Type elementType = typeof(T);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         DataTable t = new DataTable();
         ds.Tables.Add(t);

         //add a column to table for each public property on T
         foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
         {
             Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

             t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
         }

         //go through each property on T and add each value to the table
         foreach (T item in list)
         {
             DataRow row = t.NewRow();

             foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
             {
                 row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
             }

             t.Rows.Add(row);
         }

         return ds;
     }

    }
}
```

EDIT: formatted spacing to make all code show-up in codeblock